# How to engage a trigger on an object insert after a related object is inserted

Tags: apex, trigger, email

We are Using Remedyforce which has a custom object called incidents. When a client creates an incident, they can add an attachment. The order of execution for these operations is: Insert Incident, (If there are attachments) Insert Attachments. I have a requirement to send an email out on the creation of the incident but also include the attachments. Since the attachments are inserted after the incident, I cannot query for them and include them. Conversely, I can't trigger off the attachments as not every incident has them.

I'm exploring using a future method to send the email but I'm not sure that will be 100% reliable as the documentation states " the method executes when Salesforce has available resources". Can I be 100% certain that this will not run until all the attachments have been inserted?
Is there another methodology for accomplishing this?

The only other option I have considered is to send the email from the incident and then send another with the attachments, although it doesn't meet my requirement.

Answer (score 2):

The time delay between an `Incident` being inserted and a related `Attachment` being inserted is open ended - depends how quick the person using the system is. So I would suggest picking a time window - e.g. 5 minutes - and saying that if that time window has gone by with no more Attachments being added the email should be sent.

This could be implement via polling by writing a [Schedulable](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_interface_system_schedulable.htm) that queries for recently inserted `Incident` objects (via their CreatedDate) and also checks the related `Attachment` objects (via the ParentId). If you don't need the emails to go out immediately this could be scheduled to run once an hour quite simply using a '0 0 * * * ?' cron expression.

Comment: This may work. It is a notification of high priority so it needs to be sent asap. I will find out if the 5 minute window will work.

Answer (score 1):

You could also create a time based workflow rule to set a checkbox field on the Incident record 1 hour after the Incident was created, if like Keith said, the email doesn't have to go out immediately. Then have your trigger send out the email and uncheck the box upon success.